# Intent in Android developer

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two "Intent" from different Activity?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_padres);

    TextView mTextViewNom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNew2);
    TextView mTextViewAp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNew3);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String usuario = intent.getStringExtra("Usuario");
    mTextViewNom.setText(usuario);
    String apellido = intent.getStringExtra("Apellidos");
    mTextViewAp.setText(apellido);

    TextView mTextViewMedia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNew4);
    int mediaObtenida = 0;

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int media = intent2.getIntExtra("Media", mediaObtenida);
    mTextViewMedia.setText(String.valueOf(media));

}
```

How I can specify URI in getIntent();???

Answer (score 0):

Store your URI as a string 
`intent.putExtra("MyURI".toString());`
Then just corvert it again
`Uri testURI = Uri.parse(extras.getString("MyURI"));`